# Views in fragment not showing up when fragment is popped from backstack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments: one for entering names, and one that uses the list of names. On the second fragment there is a previous button to go back to the first fragment to edit the names.  When the "previous" button is pressed, every programmatically generated EditText disappears, except for the one specified in the xml.
[The first fragment before pressing next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQyr6.png)

[The second page with the previous button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baKZN.png)

[The first fragment after previous is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwqia.png)

This is how I'm inflating the Edittexts:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edittext,null);
editText.setHint("Roommate " + counter);
editText.requestFocus();
layout.addView(editText);
```

I've tried re-inflating completely new edittexts which still do not show up.  Any suggestions would be fantastic

EDIT: Instead of replacing fragment 1 with fragment 2 I tried using getSupportFragmentManager().add(...) instead of .replace(...) and It now works as it should

Comment: How are you starting the activity? Is it an intent that doesn't return a result? If I understand correctly perhaps this can help: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html